# Ajax appended drop down submitting null value

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am using the following code to clear then append values to a drop down select menu.

Problem is when the form is submitted the value sent for the drop down is null.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#sel_year").change(function(){



            var deptid = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'model_search.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {Year:deptid},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){

                    var len = response.length;

                    $("#sel_model").empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                        var id = response[i]['ID'];
                        var name = response[i]['model_name'];

                        $("#sel_model").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");

                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Then the HTML

```
    <form action='menu.php' method="POST">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Auto populate dropdown</h1>
        <div id="div_content">
         <div>Year </div>
         <select name="Year" id="sel_year">
           <option value="0">- Select -</option>
           <option value="1996">1996</option>
           <option value="1997">1997</option>
           <option value="1998">1998</option>
         </select>

         <div>Model </div>
         <select  name='sel_model' id="sel_model">
           <option value="1">- Select Year First-</option>
         </select>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
```

Submitting the form results in:

```
Array ( [Year] => 2001 [sel_model] => null
```

I just don't understand why the value is null.

Comment: What does `response` return?

Comment: All you send is a year. No `sel_model` sent in  `data:{Year:deptid}`

Comment: The ajax part works fine, the model names are added to the drop down, but when I submit the form I get 
Array ( [Year] => 2001 [sel_model] => null

Comment: Looking at response was the key. I wasn't sending back a value to place in the drop down.